# How to see VB.net Designer when Live Sharing Someone

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I and my friend are developing a visual basic app and I can't see the designer, only the code. Shift F7 and right-clicking to open the designer doesn't work. If I can't do it without downloading the files is there a way to sync the project files with live share?

Comment: Live share won't sync files.  You can look at using DevOps or possibly OneDrive for that.

Comment: But is there any way me and my friend can code at the same time while both of us can see the designer.

Comment: I don't know for sure as I've never tried before but I wouldn't be surprised if it's not possible because sharing a designer would be different to sharing code.